# OpenURL fails to open some very specific URL and shows error "Download Failed"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to open some URLs with Safari browser of apple device. And my openURL function works fine most of the time. However when I tried to open this URL, it failed with the following **error**.

> Download Failed Safari cannot download file.

Here is the URL that fails:
https://www.youtube.com/v/QH2-TGUlwu4?version=3&autohide=1

Here is my code:

```
let url = "https://www.youtube.com/v/QH2-TGUlwu4?version=3&amp;autohide=1"
if let nsurl = NSURL(string: url){
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(nsurl){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(nsurl)
    }else{
        print("Cannot open this NSURL.")
    }
}else{
    print("Cannot convert String to NSURL.")
}
```

Comment: Problem is your URL is not opening in Safari browser too, try to open it in Safari and you find the issue.

Comment: if let appURL = NSURL(string: "uengage://") {
            
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appURL) {
                print("Able to open uengage app")
            } else {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/v/QH2-TGUlwu4?version=3&amp;autohide=1")!) try this
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you mentioned
https://www.youtube.com/v/QH2-TGUlwu4?version=3&autohide=1
contains a SWF file i.e. Shockwave Flash file.

Flash cannot played on an iOS based device ([link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5592238?tstart=0)).

1) Either you need to show appropriate error message to user.

2) Or you can redirect user to YouTube app (instead of Safari), where user would be able stream and watch the video.
See this [Apple doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html) to understand how to redirect user to YouTube app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode URL before use it like:

```
let urlString = "https://www.youtube.com/v/QH2-TGUlwu4?version=3&amp;autohide=1"
var escapedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

if let nsurl = NSURL(string: escapedString){
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(nsurl){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(nsurl)
    }else{
        print("Cannot open this NSURL.")
    }
}else{
    print("Cannot convert String to NSURL.")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this? It didnt work for me. Console says: canOpenURL: failed for URL: "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fv%2FQH2-TGUlwu4%3Fversion=3&amp;autohide=1" - error: "Invalid input URL"
Cannot open this NSURL.

Comment: No, Can you please try `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet`